# Invalid suspense option usage in next/dynamic

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-suspense

I have a loader component and I want it to appear while my page is rendering.
According to the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import), when using suspense my code should look like this

```
const DynamicLazyComponent = dynamic(() => import('../components/loader'), {
    suspense: true,
})

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <>
            <Suspense fallback={`loading`}>
                <DynamicLazyComponent />
                ...some code here...
            </Suspense>
        </>
    )
}
```

But I end up with an error that says

> Invalid suspense option usage in next/dynamic. Read more:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-dynamic-suspense

I'm sure I followed what the docs stated, but I'm not sure as to why I'm getting these errors.

Comment: Note that it only works on client-side or server-side with fallback

Comment: @Nico Is there a way I could show a loader component while the page is rendering? If this were React, I'd be using suspense fallback

Comment: @Nico `works on client-side or server-side` , in the code above it's generating on ssg ?.
adding `{ suspense: true, ssr: false }` could help?

Comment: @ChemiAdel Added what you said, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

To use suspense option in Next JS, you need next 12, react 18 and react-dom 18.

You can see more detail information here. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/react-18/overview

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).